# How to make a dropdown button stay open after clicking on content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown button **http://fiddle.jshell.net/65q4r/**

And now I'm trying to achieve 2 things:

1. When the dropdown links are clicked or anywhere inside the dropdown
   remains open.
2. Have two of these in the same page that work independently.

Thank you all!!

Comment: `if (e.target==this)` will tell you if the element is the actual one you clicked, not a parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two minor tweaks to your JS: http://fiddle.jshell.net/65q4r/7/

lines 4-5:

```
$('.clicker').click(function(e) {
    $('+ ul', $(this)).slideToggle(200);
```

and added this handler:

```
$('.click-nav > ul ul a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

also added second button to html to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/65q4r/6/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="click-nav">
    <ul class="no-js">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="clicker">Dropdown Button</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="click-nav">
    <ul class="no-js">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="clicker">Dropdown Button</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
.price {
    color: #820C8E;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-weight: bold
}

.click-nav {
    float:left
}
.click-nav ul {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-size:14px
}
.click-nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.click-nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker {
    position: relative;
    color: #494949;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover, .click-nav ul .active {
}
.click-nav img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 0;
}
.click-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 22px;
    background: #FFF;
}
.click-nav ul li li a{
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 62px 0 22px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {
}
/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {
    display: none;
}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.click-nav .clicker').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if($(e.target).attr('href') == '#') {e.preventDefault();}
e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('*:not(.click-nav):not(.click-nav *)').click(function (e) {
        $(".js ul").slideUp(200);
        $(".clicker").removeClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. Almost there. I just need to close it when clicked outside like in my demo.
Thanks!

Comment: @user1628193 There you go.

Comment: Now when I click on the button it disappears. Is it the same fiddle link?

Comment: @user1628193 I modified the answer.

Comment: It's still closing when click on links. But no worries as I have a valid answer now. Thanks a lot ;)